# C# open form return string on closing

Tags: .net

how to return string onclosing winform (.net 2)

for example winform_1 opens winform_2, onclosing winform_2 returns a string to winform_1. please keep in mind no Dialog box.

thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "no dialog box"?

Comment: well, when you open a dialog box you cannot use the main form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Return" suggests that something within the first form is blocking on the second form, which sounds odd to me if it's not a dialog.

One thing you *could* do is have a string property within the second form, then do:

```
// In FirstForm.cs
secondForm.FormClosing += HandleSecondFormClosing;

...

private void HandleSecondFormClosing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Or just use your existing reference to the second form, if you
    // still have it
    SecondForm form = (SecondForm) sender;

    // Or whatever else you want to do with the result in SecondForm.
    // OperationResult is the name of the string property you've put
    // in SecondForm.
    result.Text = form.OperationResult;
}
```

Obviously rename all of these arbitrary names to something more meaningful...

Comment: Thank you guys i have tried out all suggestion. but this is exactly what i was look for,

Answer (score 1):

Make the value a public property of winform_2 and read it from winform_1 after it closes.

Then rename your winform classes :(

Answer (score 1):

Use a property on winform_2.

```
public class winform_2 : Form {

    public string MyReturnValue{ get; set; }

    public void SetMyString(){
        MyReturnValue = "return value";
    }
}

public class winform_1 : Form { 

    private void CallForm2(){
        var form2 = new winform_2();
        form2.ShowDialog();
        var resultString = form2.MyReturnValue;
    }
}
```